# What is the difference between an object and a prototype in prototypal programming?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototypal-inheritance, prototype-programming

I'm trying to understand the "JavaScript way" of creating and using objects and I think I'm running into a misunderstanding of an object and a prototype.

In a new project I've started I've decided to try out prototypal inheritance. I'm confused if this means I should just create an object that I intend to use and then create other objects based on that using `Object.create()` such as:

```
var labrador = {
   color: 'golden',
   sheds: true,

   fetch: function()
   {
      // magic
   }
};

var jindo = Object.create(dog);
jindo.color = 'white';
```

Or if I should create a kind of class and that create instances of that using `Object.create()`.

```
var Dog = { // Is this class-like thing a prototype?
   color: null,
   sheds: null,

   fetch: function()
   {
      // magic
   }
};

var labrador = Object.create(Dog);
labrador.color = 'golden';
labrador.sheds = true;

var jindo = Object.create(Dog);
jindo.color = 'white';
jindo.sheds = true;
```

Having much more experience in Class-based OOP the latter method feels more comfortable to me (and maybe that's reason enough). But I feel like the spirit of prototypal inheritance is more in the first option.

Which method is more in the "spirit" of prototypal programming? Or am I completely missing the point?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `prototype` is just another object to which an object has an implicit reference.

When you do:

```
var obj = Object.create( some_object );
```

...you're saying that you want `obj` to try to fetch properties from `some_object`, when they don't exist on `obj`.

As such, your second example would be closer to the way you'd use it. Every object that is created using `Object.create(Dog)` will have in its *prototype chain*, that `Dog` object. So if you make a change to `Dog`, the change will be reflected across all the objects that have `Dog` in the chain.

If the main object has the same property as exists on the prototype object, that property is *shadowing* that property of the prototype. An example of that would be the `null` values you set on properties of `Dog`.

If you do:

```
var lab = Object.create(Dog);
lab.color = 'golden';
```

...you're now shadowing the `color` property on `Dog`, so you'll no longer get `null`. You're *not* changing `Dog` in any way, so if I create another object:

```
var colorless_dog = Object.create(Dog);
```

...this one will still get the `null` value from the prototype chain when accessing the `color` property.

```
colorless_dog.color;  // null
```

...until you shadow it:

```
colorless_dog.color = 'blue';
colorless_dog.color;  // 'blue'
```

So given your example:

```
var lab = Object.create(Dog);
lab.color = 'golden';
lab.sheds = true;
```

...it looks something like this:

```
              // labrador              // Dog
lab.color---> color:'golden'           color:null
lab.sheds---> sheds:true               sheds:null

lab.fetch()--------------------------> fetch: function() {
                                          alert( this.color ); // 'golden'
                                          // "this" is a reference to the
                                          //    "lab" object, instead of "Dog"
                                       }
```

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful. It seems that there isn't anything necessarily against the "spirit" of prototypal programming in the first example, but it could potentially be a pain to maintain.

Comment: @donut: Well in the first example, it depends on what `dog` is. If you meant to use `labrador`, and `labrador` had `dog` in its prototype chain, and all `labrador`s are `color:'golden'` and `sheds:true` then, yes, it would make sense to do that. You can extend the prototype chain across many objects as long as it makes sense to. If `fetch()` should apply to all `dog`s, then it would make more sense to have that on `dog` than on `labrador`.

Answer (score 3):

A prototype is just an object.

It's any object that another object uses as it's prototype.

Comment: These statements are technically correct. However, they don't help answering the question, so -1

Comment: @delnan - So it goes, I guess. There were no other answers when I provided mine.  I lacked the time for a full discussion, so I provided the central concept necessary to understand the topic.