# SyntaxError when extending Number object

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, prototype, literals

I am trying to extend the `Number` object with this code:

```js
Number.prototype.isNumber = function(i){
  if(arguments.length === 1){
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(i)) && isFinite(i);
  } else {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(this)) && isFinite(this);
  }
}

try {
  var x = 8.isNumber();
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

I get `SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal`

also when I try the following:

```
Number.isNumber(8)
```

I get `Number.isNumber is not a function`!!

Comment: You don't really expect JS to be able to distinguish between 8.isNumber and 8.123456 do you?

Comment: Well, you won't be able to do `8.anything` because JS syntax. `Number.isNumber` *isn't* a function, but `var n = 8; n.isNumber()` does what you'd expect. (As the answer indicates, you can turn it into a working version with `()`, which probably isn't the syntax you want. But if you're not using it on immediates, it's fine.

Comment: @ChrisCaviness No reason it couldn't, it just doesn't. Ruby, for example, would parse this just fine.

Comment: I think the whole concept is flawed. `variable.isNumber()` only works, if the parser does a type check and accepts the literal as `typeof variable === "number`, otherwise it throws an error. What you instead want, is to directly extend `Number`, not the prototype so you can run `Number.isNumber(variable)`.

Comment: @Christoph Lol, good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript parser reads `8.isNumber` as a number literal.

To access a `Number` method on a numeric literal you'll have to surround the number with parenthesis so the JavaScript interpreter knows you're trying to use the number properties.

```js
Number.prototype.isNumber = function(i) {
  if (arguments.length === 1) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(i)) && isFinite(i);
  } 

  return !isNaN(parseFloat(this)) && isFinite(this);
}

try {
  var x = (8).isNumber();
  console.log(x);
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: "Try putting" is not a very convincing answer. Why does it work? Explain what it means to extend the "Number" prototype. What are literals, etc...

Comment: or use `..`  like `var x = 8..isNumber()`. The first `.` is the decimal point, and the second `.` is the object property accessor. (*not that i suggest such usage, but just for reference and understanding*)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't help it but provide an additional answer although you already accepted one.

The first thing you need to know, is that there is a fundamental difference between the `Number` object, and the `Number` prototype ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558872/what-is-the-difference-between-an-object-and-a-prototype-in-prototypal-programmi)).

As it stands, you are extending the `Number` prototype, not the object itself! Your `isNumber` implementation actually has the same effect like the following:

```
Number.prototype.isNumber = function(){return isFinite(this)}
```

Why? Because in order to execute this prototype method, the parser first needs to know the type of the literal you are invoking the function on. That's why you either need to turn your number literal into an expression by wrapping it in parentheses: `(8).isNumber()` or by using an even weirder notation `8..isNumber()` (the first `.` is the decimal point, the second the property accessor). At this point, the javascript engine already evaluated it as a `Number` and thus can execute the `isNumber()` method.

On the other hand, although at first glimpse your code looks like it could handle the following case correctly (since you are doing a parseFloat): `"8".isNumber()` will always throw an exception, because here we have a string literal, and the `String` prototype does not have the according method. This means, you will never be able to detect numbers that are actually string literals in the first place.

What you instead should do, is directly extend the `Number` object so you can actually do a proper check without having to deal with errors:

```
Number.isFiniteNumber = function(i){
    return !Number.isNaN(i) && Number.isFinite(i);
}

Number.isFiniteNumber(8);        // returns true
Number.isFiniteNumber("3.141");  // returns true
Number.isFiniteNumber(".2e-34"); // returns true
Number.isFiniteNumber(Infinity); // returns false

// just for informational purposes
typeof Infinity === "number" // is true
```

**Bonus material:**

[Extending native objects is potentially dangerous](http://perfectionkills.com/extending-native-builtins/).

[`Number.isNaN()` probably does not what you think it does.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176459/is-number-isnan-more-broken-than-isnan)